# Set the environment of a knitr chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I have an RStudio notebook and I want to set the notebook chunks to operate inside a custom R environment. I want to do this because I am actually working with multiple notebooks in the same project, and they share a number of variables and functions but ultimately do slightly different analyses. I'm using the same RStudio instance and therefore the same R instance, but I don't want to worry about overwriting variables when I go back and forth between the notebooks.

I know I can do this for a whole document with the `envir` argument to `knitr::knit()`, but since I'm using RStudio notebooks interactively I want to set the environment at the chunk level, rather than the document level. The ideal scenario would be an Rmd document like below:

````
```{r setup}
my.environment = new.env(parent = globalenv())
knitr_opts$set(envir = my.environment)
```
... markdown content...

```{r another-chunk}
a = 5  # a is assigned in my.environment 
```
````

Of course, the above is not possible because there is no `envir` knitr option.

I think the solution might be using a knitr hook. An ideal solution would look something like this:

```
knit_hook$set(set_envir = function(before, options, envir){
  if(before)
    set.environment(options$set_envir)
  else
    set.envir(globalenv())
})
```

Of course, this isn't possible because there's no `set.envir` function in R that allows you set your current working environment.

The actual solution is probably using something like `with` or `within`, or passing chunk contents to a function as an `shquote` or something like that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Further research suggests this isn't possible... the reason being the "run" button in RStudio just sources the code chunk, rather than running it through `knitr`.